# Was the takeover of Polish state media constitutional?

Tags: poland, rule-of-law

In December 2023, after the formation of Donald Tusk's coalition government, the Sejm adopted a [resolution](https://orka.sejm.gov.pl/proc10.nsf/uchwaly/117_u.htm) about "restoring the legal order and the impartiality and integrity of the public media". After this, the minister of culture and national heritage, Bartłomiej Sienkiewicz dismissed Mateusz Matyszkowicz as the head of TVP, and appointed Tomasz Sygut in his place.

This move was controversial, as members of the former governing party PiS called the action unconstitutional.

What can we say about this? Was the appointment of the new head of media in accordance with Polish law?

Comment: No, it wasn't. I don't have enough time to write an answer this year, but you can have a look on [statement of Helsinki Foundation for Human Rights](https://hfhr.pl/aktualnosci/stanowisko-hfpc-ws-zmian-w-mediach-publicznych) (in Polish)

Comment: I suspect it is too early to give a definitive answer. Clearly there is a debate. So different opinions.  It is normally a Constitutional court (or similar) that gives an authoritative answer, anything else is just another opinion (perhaps an expert opinion, but not authoritative)

Comment: AFAICT the new gov't reject the legality of the body that PiS created and which appointed the old director https://notesfrompoland.com/2023/12/27/polish-public-media-crisis-deepens-as-former-ruling-party-appoints-alternative-head-of-state-tv/ The PiS president Duda obviously disagrees.

Comment: @JamesK another [piece](https://notesfrompoland.com/2023/12/26/three-legal-views-on-the-polish-governments-public-media-takeover/) in the same venue finds a Polish law professor who says it was legal, so of course YMMV.

Comment: @JamesK: interestingly, PiS itself relied on an act that declared unconstitutional to do their [prior] takeover of the TV. But as long as Duda is president, that act can't be formally repealed (because Duda would veto that). As it turns out, the title and the body of the Q ask to different things. Unconstitutional  laws can apparently remain on the books in Poland.

Comment: @Fizz That explains the conflict and where the different opinions come from, maybe put that as an answer.

Comment: interesting question

Comment: Voting not to close - The question *Was the appointment of the new head of media in accordance with Polish law?* can be factually answered by citing legal experts. Such "opinions" by experts are based on precedents, deductive and legal reasoning, and thus are not speculative opinions.